# include same header in 2 files .c

Tags: c, header, include

c files : Primitives.c, bloc.c and main.c
And 2.h headers: bloc.h and primitives.h
I want to work on Primitives.c and use bloc.c functions i made`#include "primitives.h"`in primitives.c
In primitives.h I have :

```
#ifndef PRIMITIVES_H_
#define PRIMITIVES_H_
#include "bloc.h"

#endif
```

In bloc.h :

```
#ifndef BLOC_H_
#define BLOC_H_
...
#endif
```

In primitives.c:

```
#include "primitives.h"
printf ("%d", var);
```

Finaly in bloc.c : i putted
    int var =2;

The problem is that it shows me when I compile primitives.c:
primitives.c:5:9: erreur: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant ( in french sorry )

Comment: Is that all of `primitives.c`? Do you include `stdio`?

Comment: in bloc.h i include everything.. then bloc.h included in primitives.h, does it work like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not put the line:  printf ("%d", var);
below the include. It must be placed in a function.

Comment: It was that.But i have a question ; bloc.h I sould include it in primitives.h or primitives.c ?

Comment: it depends on your architecture.
If primitives.h use any definitions of bloc.h, it should include bloc.h .  
If only primitives.c use structs/variables/definitions of bloc.h, you should include bloc.h in c source.
However, I recommend not include header file .h in another .h file.